# Change the y-axis with percentage of a barplot the pixel values of a raster

Tags: raster, r

I have a raster that includes more than 120 million pixel values and it has values of 0,1,10,11. I would like to create a barplot to show their frequencies;

```
barplot(diff_raster)
```

gives me this;

[image: barplot]

But, I would like Y-axis to show the percentage of those pixels' values, not the amount. How can I make this? or Can you give me any other suggestions to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The `barplot()` function dose not generate a *histogram,* but a *barplot*.

For generate a *histogram* with the stard functions of R you must use the `hist()` function :

```
hist(raster)
```

You can also use the `density()` function for generate a density curve :

```
plot(density(raster))
```